# How to remove unwanted expo modules

Tags: react-native, expo

When creating an react native app with expo, expo installs many module that i don't need. Is there a way to remove these unwanted modules like barcode reader google sign in and google maps.
thanks

Comment: Unfortunately removing Universal Modules and ExpoKit Modules is not that straight forward.Check out this document https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/universal-modules-and-expokit/

Comment: You could remove them with Yarn remove.  Expo uses Yarn.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?@picacode

Comment: Hi @pvuidev you can now remove them simply by using `npm uninstall` or `yarn remove` check out @akshay-i 's answer, but be careful if you are using OTA https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/universal-modules-and-expokit

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To remove a package from your `node_modules` directory, on the command line, use the uninstall command. Include the scope of the package is scoped.

Unscoped package

```
npm uninstall --save <package_name>
```

Scoped package

```
npm uninstall --save <@scope/package_name>
```

if need to know more about it then follow official Document here https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#removing-a-local-package-from-the-packagejson-dependencies

Comment: It is really strange but command "npm uninstall package-name" doesn't delete packege from folder and doesn't delete it from package.json.

Answer (score 12):

`npm uninstall <package name>` works. It removes the expo module from your `node_modules`

for more reference 
https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies

Comment: or `yarn remove <package name>` if you use Yarn

Answer (score 7):

## With NPM

```
$ npm uninstall jest
```

## Shorthand version

```
$ npm r jest
```

## With Yarn

```
$ yarn remove jest
```

Comment: I tried this after `expo install expo-camera`, but then if I wanted to install another module I get `PluginError: Failed to resolve plugin for module "expo-camera" relative to ...` **I had to go to `app.json` (in project root) and remove `"expo-camera"` from the "plugins" array**